# Why do air compressors have separate inlets/outlets?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, air

Our fridge recently broke down, and now I'd like to turn the leftover compressor into an air compressor. I've also got an old tank from a water pump. This one has only 1 opening. All the air compressors I have seen, however, have 2 openings, besides the pressure release valves. One entrypoint, and one exit. Even tutorials I've found online specifically go out of their way to drill a second hole into their tank. Why is that? If possible, I'd like to simply put a T-Fitting over the opening, both for input and output. Why does nobody does this/why is this a bad idea. Sorry for the offtopic question, but I didnt know wherelse to post a question on the physics of air compression.

Comment: A refrigerator is a continuous flow device, so the compressor always has  low pressure vapor flowing in and, simultaneously, an equal mass of high pressure vapor flowing out.

Comment: Yes, but that's the compressor. I want to hook this compressor up to an air tank to create your standart garage compressor, where the air enters the (fridge) compressor, then exits it into the air tank, where over time through continuous addition of air pressure builds. On normal tanks there is a separate outlet, but I want to access the pressurized air directly from the inlet. The inlets and outlets of the fridge compressor are separated from the inlets and outlets of the tank It works this way: Compressor Inlet -> Compressor Outlet -> Air Tank In let -> Air Tank -> Air Tank Outlet, i.e. user